Why is Grid Layout causing overflow in x direction?
I'am building a simple UI with Nextjs(app router) + Tailwindcss.
While Building a simple grid layout of cards, problem occurs when there are more than 2 lines of boxes.
If there are only 1 line of the Cards, the total width are well performed to be the viewport.
But if there are more than 2 lines of boxes, overflow x occurs.
Image of Situation
Success
Problem
I also observed that all the highest container has the same width.
Code Specification
const MainPage = ({}: MainPageProps): ReactNode => {
  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen-header relative flex h-min flex-grow flex-col items-center justify-start bg-white px-10'>
      {/* 제목 */}
      <div className='flex h-[8dvh] min-h-[60px] w-full items-end justify-start gap-4'>
        <span className='text-2xl font-semibold xl:text-3xl'>내 여행 계획</span>
        <span className='text-sm font-medium xl:text-base'>10개</span>
      </div>
      {/* 필터 / 검색 */}
      <MobileMenu className='md:hidden' />
      <DesktopMenu className='hidden md:flex' />
      {/* 카드 */}
      {/* Todo: 개수 고정 (8) */}
      <div className='relative grid w-full grid-cols-1 gap-6 overflow-x-hidden sm:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4'>
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
        <PlanCard data={dummy_plan} />
      </div>
      {/* 페이지네이션 */}
      <CustomPagination className='py-4' />
    </div>
  )
}

// PlanCard
const PlanCard = ({ data }: PlanCardProps): ReactNode => {
  return (
    <div className='flex h-min w-full flex-col justify-start gap-4 overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white p-3 shadow-tb-shadow'>
      <Image src={data.imageSrc} alt='Plan Image' className='aspect-video w-full rounded-md object-cover' />
      <div className='relative'>
        <div className='flex items-end justify-start gap-3'>
          <h2 className='text-lg font-bold lg:text-xl'>{data.title}</h2>
          <span className='text-xs'>{data.region}</span>
        </div>

        <p className='flex items-center pb-5 pt-2 text-xs lg:text-sm'>{data.description}</p>

        <div className='flex items-center justify-between text-xs lg:text-sm'>
          <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
            <div className='flex items-center gap-1'>
              <LucideIcon color='tbRed' name='Heart' strokeWidth={3} />
              <span>{data.likes}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center gap-1'>
              <LucideIcon name='MessageCircle' strokeWidth={3} />
              <span>{data.comments}</span>
            </div>
            <div className='flex items-center gap-1'>
              <LucideIcon name='Bookmark' strokeWidth={3} />
              <span>{data.scraps}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span>{data.schedule}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

My solution
On global.css I applied overflow-x:hidden on body.
@layer base {
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    @apply border-border;
  }
  body {
    @apply bg-background text-foreground;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}

Beside this Solution I'am wishing an more theoretical reason and solution.
I'm guessing that scrollbar of height is causing it.
So, I change the width main from w-screen to w-dvw but this didn't work.
Please Help

use overflow-x-hidden to stop it
